# Android onBackStackChanged() not called

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I have an `Activity` like the code below:

```
public class AuthenticatedMainActivity extends Activity implements FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        .............
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();           
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame_container,fragment, "First").addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }

    private void switchFragment(Fragment fragment){            
      FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
      fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).addToBackStack("Tag").commit();
    }

    @Override
public void onBackStackChanged() {
    System.out.println("====================================================changeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee");
}       
}
```

But the `onBackStackChanged()` method is never called even After successfully replaced fragments with the `switchFragment` method.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to add your `Activity` as a `OnBackStackChangedListener` using `addOnBackStackChangedListener`.

Example:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    .............
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();     
    fragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(this);      
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame_container,fragment, "First").addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
```

Comment: Turns out you have to explicitly call: .addToBackStack(null) otherwise onBackStackChanged is not called even when correctly registered!

Comment: @BenMartenThat's because fragment transactions are not added to backstack by default.

Answer (score 0):

the only thing needed is to do this onCreate:

```
getFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(this);
```