# Android BackStack issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack, fragment-backstack

I am having trouble fixing a problem that I have with the BackStack. I have 3 fragments that are managed by an Activity:

[image]

The navigation between the fragments I using this code:

```
private void showFragment(BabysitFragment babysitFragment, UserRequest userRequest) {
   FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
   switch (babysitFragment) {
      case CHILDREN_OVERVIEW:
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Fragment childrenSpecification = ChildrenOverviewFragment.newInstance(userRequest);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, childrenSpecification, BabysitFragment.CHILDREN_OVERVIEW.getSimpleName()).commit();
        break;
      case CHILD_SPECIFICATION:
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Fragment childSpecification = ChildSpecificationFragment.newInstance(userRequest);
        fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, childSpecification, BabysitFragment.CHILD_SPECIFICATION.getSimpleName()).commit();
        break;
   }
}

//Gets called by FinalizeFrag and ChildSpecificationFrag
@Override
public void onChildrenOverviewNeeded(UserRequest userRequest) {
    showFragment(BabysitFragment.CHILDREN_OVERVIEW, userRequest);
}

//Gets called by ChildrenOverviewFrag
@Override
public void onChildSpecificationNeeded(UserRequest userRequest) {
    showFragment(BabysitFragment.CHILD_SPECIFICATION, userRequest);
}
```

I want the user  to be able to go back to the FinalizeFrag using the backbutton from the other 2 fragments. This works with the current code but In 1 flow I do have a problem:

1. The users saves the new 'Child' in the ChildSpecificationFrag (save icon in the toolbar)
2. User gets redirected to the ChildrenOverviewFrag
3. User presses back button
4. Stays on the ChildrenOverviewFrag (SHOULD redirect to the FinalizeFrag)

NOTE: when I press the button again it does redirect to the FinalizeFrag

Code when clicking the close button (ChildSpecificationFragment):

```
if (id == android.R.id.home) {
  getActivity().onBackPressed();
}
```

Code when clicking the save button (ChildSpecificationFragment):

```
...
userRequest.getFamilyDetails().getChildren().add(child);
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
onChildrenOverviewNeededListener.onChildrenOverviewNeeded(userRequest, this);
```

As you can see I am removing the Fragment from the BackStack. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call addToBackStack, before doing "User gets redirected to the ChildrenOverviewFrag",

Comment: In the case of CHILDREN_OVERVIEW or CHILD_SPECIFICATION? Can you also explain why? Thanks!

Comment: Try both. Please let me know if it works. I had used it long back and it did work for me.

Comment: I've replaced it with 'fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("scheduleFragment");' in both cases but I still need to click back 2 times in the ChildrenOverviewFrag to go back to the FinalizeFrag.

Comment: It seems like `onbackstackchangedlistener` can solve your issue

Comment: And how does it help?

Comment: BTW, where are you committing the fragment transaction?

Comment: On the end of the fragmentTransaction.replace(...).commit() line.

Comment: I see. Before doing "User gets redirected to the ChildrenOverviewFrag", don't call addToBackStack

Comment: This seems to work but now The content of the ChildrenOverviewFrag shows under the FinalizeFrag like so: http://imgur.com/yZlpFC6. Do I have to remove the ChildrenOverviewFrag  in some way?

Comment: Yes. You need to override `onbackstackchangedlistener` and when you return to FinalyzeFrag, you need to remove contents of ChildrenOverviewFrag

Comment: I am still not sure how you want the onbackstackchangedlistener to look like? Can you maybe give a code example?

Comment: See it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23599519/android-onbackstackchanged-not-called

Comment: How do I know that I am going from the ChildrenOverviewFrag  to the FinalyzeFrag? Sorry for all these questions :S

Comment: I think `getBackStackEntryCount()` can be used to determine where are you. When you return to `finalyzeFrag`, can back stack entry count be used here?

Comment: You can also handle things in `onResume` of finalyzeFrag. See here on how to force call `onResume` of a fragment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503189/fragments-onresume-from-back-stack

Comment: The count it 1 in both situations: from finalize to overview, from specification to overview. So it seems impossible for me to know when to clear.

Comment: Sigh! I can think of one more approach, though it is kinda hack. Use `SharedPreferences` and write a value to it whenever user saves a child. In this way, you know that when to handle it after checking content of `SharedPreferences`. Once you handle it, clean the value of `SharedPreferences` so that it can be used next time user saves a new child

Comment: And when do you suppose I read from the preferences and clear the container?

Comment: Inside onBackStackChanged method

Comment: I am going to try some stuff, I suppose I also have to check that I am currently displaying the FinalizeFrag.

Comment: Let me know if you get stuck into any issue

Comment: I will, thanks for the help! The SharedPreferences solution seems a bit dodgy but I am looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

i think

```
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
```

will  add fragment to back stack.

```
public abstract boolean popBackStackImmediate (String name, int flags)
```

just returns true if there was something popped, else false.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, this is what I found on the docs:

Like popBackStack(), but performs the operation immediately inside of the call. This is like calling executePendingTransactions() afterwards.


Returns true if there was something popped, else false. It does seem to me that It pops the latest added item.