# How to set the side bar menu item selected when fragment changes on click of back button?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzPwS.png)How can I set the side bar menu item selected when fragment changes on click of the back button. I have custom textview and layouts in side bar:
I tried  this onBackStackChanged() method onBack press on Main activity of fragment, but I get last fragment selected in menu

```
@Override
public void onBackStackChanged()
{
    String Tag = " ";
     Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(Tag);
    Log.e("frag",""+fragment);
    if (Tag != null) {
        switch (Tag) {
            case "Dashboard":
            menu_img_dashboard.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.iconactivedasboard));
            menu_dashborad_ln.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorTextPrimary));
            menu_img_newproduct.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.iconnewproduct));
            menu_newproduct_ln.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colormenugray));
            menu_img_searchbycategory.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.iconsearch));
            menu_searchbycategory_ln.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colormenugray));
            menu_img_orderhistory.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.iconorederhistory));
            menu_myorderhistory_ln.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colormenugray));
            menu_img_myfavorite.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.iconfavourite));
            menu_myfavorite_ln.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colormenugray));
            menu_img_about.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.iconabout));
            menu_about_ln.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colormenugray));
            menu_img_helpdesk.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.iconhelpdesk));
            menu_helpdesk_ln.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colormenugray));
            Log.v("hy", "find the dash fragment");

            break;}
```

Comment: Please explain what you are doing and what do you want to do. You can share some images of your menu and flow of navigation. Trim the code you share to show your main purpose

Comment: @Golnar i attach the screen shot please check

Comment: Trace and check if  onBackStackChanged() gets called when you  return to main page

Comment: @Golnar   onbackstackchnged method is not working and i have 7 fragments that are dashboard ,newproduct ,search,order,favorite,helpdesk,about.when i got through dashboard >newproduct>productdetails then press backbutton i get current fragment on dashboard is new product

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23599519/android-onbackstackchanged-not-called

Comment: okay thank you@Golnar